# Extract untarred files from a tgz in linux

Tags: vmware, tar

I have a large .tgz file which is of very large size(19GB). I started the untar operation in vmware last night but in the morning, I saw a blue screen of death. I dont want to waste time on untarring the files that are already done(5GB). How do I untar the files that are not yet untarred into the same folder without wasting time on 5GB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for tar:

```
-k, --keep-old-files
```

> keep existing files; don't overwrite them from archive

I also recommend (if applicable):

```
--keep-newer-files
```

> do not overwrite files which are newer than the archive

Therefore, you probably want something like this:

```
tar -zx -v -k --keep-newer-files -f yourbigtar.tgz
```